# is it possible to use viewflipper in a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, viewflipper

I am using view flipper in a fragment, its a simple viewflipper which changes the view on press of a button, but it is not working, however it works when I use the same code in a different independent project. what can be the reason

```
public class Random extends Fragment {

ViewFlipper viewFlipper;
Button Next, Previous,btn;


public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.random,
            container, false);
    viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper)v.findViewById(R.id.ViewFlipper01);

    Next = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.Next);
    Previous = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.Previous);
    btn=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.button);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "this is my Toast message!!! =)",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    Next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            viewFlipper.showNext();
        }
    });

    Previous.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            viewFlipper.showPrevious();
        }
    });

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.random, container, false);
}
```

}

Comment: check this demo i think some help you : http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/06/android-viewflipper-example.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening as you are returning new inflated view in onCreateView method after setting setOnClickListener to buttons. So, just change

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.random, container, false);
```

to

```
return v;
```